# How to connect user to courses and grades realtime database java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In this project I have two types of users (teacher and students). Teacher can add classes and student should be able to choose class and sign in to class, when student is signed in class the teacher should be able to give him a grade. I don't know how to connect user to a class and give him grades.

this is my classesAdapter

```java
public class ClassesAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Classes, ClassesAdapter.StudentViewHolder> {

    /**
     * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
     * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public ClassesAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions options) {
        super(options);
    }

    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StudentViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Classes model) {
        holder.className.setText(model.getCname());
        holder.classInfo.setText(model.getDescription());
        holder.classUid.setText(model.getUid());
        String keyId = this.getRef(position).getKey();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StudentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.classes, parent, false);

        return new ClassesAdapter.StudentViewHolder(view);

    }


    public class StudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView className;
        TextView classInfo;
        TextView classUid;
        Button classSignInBtn;

        public StudentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            className = itemView.findViewById(R.id.classNameTxt);
            classInfo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.classInfoTxt);
            classUid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.classUidTxt);
            classSignInBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.classSignInBtn);
            int position  = getAdapterPosition();
            classSignInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    String uId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("ednevnik/korisnici/" + uId);
                    DatabaseReference ref1 = db.getReference("ednevnik/razredi/");

                    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String email = snapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                            String grade = " ";
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }

                    });



                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[image: this is my real-time database]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the StackOverflow. Well, I have a similar issue with the real-time database. The issue with this type of database is that it is foresight for fast and response in real-time, which means that this type of database is for chat applications, and generally for response in real-time. My suggestion is to migrate your data to the Cloud Firestore database which is for this kind of application, I had a similar issue.

Here is the documentation for the Cloud Firestore database for Android:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Practically, this function is an issue:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String email = snapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                        String grade = " ";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }

                });
```

You are retrieving data when data is changing inside the database, and that event is not going to happen. That's why I am suggesting the Cloud Firestore database.

I guess that this helps you.
Best Regards,
Sanady

Comment: Thank you for your answer, well I'm making this app for my college and i should be using realtime database, i know that there is an problem in event listener i tried to retrive users data and put it in the table with classes data. I will try to use Cloud Firestore.

Comment: You are welcome, well I had a project for my college and I used RealTime DB, and they said that that's fine. I hope it helps you :)